# Bootstrap add close button on dropdown menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new in Bootstrap and I would like to know how to add a close button on dropdown menu.

Instead of the default Bootstrap response to toggle the menu once we click outside of it or when we click on 'no submenu items' I would like to add a close button and make it the responsible for toggling it.
The close button must goes on both menu and its submenu "see picture and the position of the close icon"

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuuII.png)

The code am working in " dropdown menu item is 'The Magazine' and the 'Travel solo' is the submenu item ": http://www.bootply.com/qYOW7v2DcM

Any suggestions would be appreciate!

Answer (score 3):

In the beginning of your html, specifically this line:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
```

you can add this line to make an `x` close button.

```
<button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>
```

maybe even put the button in its own `<li></li>` element like so:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><button type="button" class="close">&times;</button></li>
```

Then in your sub-menu's you can use the same concept.

```
<li class="menu-item dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">TRAVEL SOLO <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><button type="button" class="close">&times;</button></li>
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: It does, but there still one problem " I want to stop closing the menu when we click outside of it or when we click on 'no submenu items'  ", any clues?

Comment: Another option with a nice X for the close:  <li><button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close"></button></li>